# Pelop deleteSubColumns => NullPointerException

Tags: cassandra, pelops

This the code :

```
Selector selector = Pelops.createSelector(CASSANDRA_POOL);
Column column = selector.getSubColumnFromRow("Neighbours", user, neighbour, "Link_ID", CL_ONE);
String linkID = new String(column.getValue());
Mutator mutator = Pelops.createMutator(CASSANDRA_POOL);
System.out.println(linkID);
System.out.println(topic);
mutator.deleteSubColumns("Links",linkID,topic);
mutator.execute(CL_ONE);
```

and here the result :

```
ERROR - Exception being returned to browser when processing /ajax_request/F314921638127GLWWRG/: Message: java.lang.NullPointerException
  org.scale7.cassandra.pelops.Validation.validateColumnNames(Validation.java:60)
  org.scale7.cassandra.pelops.Mutator.deleteSubColumns(Mutator.java:724)
  org.scale7.cassandra.pelops.Mutator.deleteSubColumns(Mutator.java:698)
```

But I can't understand why it gives me the exception, the linkID and topic String have the right values.

PS : the version of cassandra is 1.0.0 and the version of pelops is 1.3-1.0.x-20111021.060203-2

Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 2):

I can't seem to replicate your issue based on the information provided, however I could replicate by passing null as the as the column name (topic in your example).

I've added a test to MutatorIntegrationTest to verify that test Mutator.deleteSubColumns works as expected and I've also made a minor change to the Validator class to avoid the NullPointerException and instead throw a org.scale7.cassandra.pelops.exceptions.ModelException.

See [MutatorIntegrationtest.testDeleteSubColumns()](https://github.com/s7/scale7-pelops/blob/48e5ce275768982d567cdd6fa5d0fed362a7c5cb/src/test/java/org/scale7/cassandra/pelops/MutatorIntegrationTest.java#L259) and [MutatorIntegrationtest. testDeleteSubColumnsWithNullColumnNameThrowsCorrectException()](https://github.com/s7/scale7-pelops/blob/48e5ce275768982d567cdd6fa5d0fed362a7c5cb/src/test/java/org/scale7/cassandra/pelops/MutatorIntegrationTest.java#L284)

So in short; make sure your 'topic' variable is not null and upgrade to the latest Pelops SNAPSHOT (for a better error message).